# how to get a placeholder value in js

Tags: javascript, placeholder

how to get a placeholder's value in javascript

I don't want **JQuery** to get the value

can anyone tell how to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const ip = document.getElementById("ip").getAttribute('placeholder');

console.log(ip);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="some value" id="ip">
```

You can use the `getAttribute()` method to get the value of an attribute of a DOM element. [MDN - Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Comment: No, if i type "Hello" in the placeholder i want to print "Hello" in the console

Comment: This does print the placeholder value in the console. If you want to get the typed value in console, you should use `document.getElementById("ip").value` [MDN - getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").placeholder;
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
First Name:
<input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Name" />

<p>Click the button to view the placeholder content in console.log</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: No, if i type "Hello" in the placeholder i want to print "Hello" in the console

Comment: Try again it will

Comment: Just press "Click Here" Button and it will display in console.log

Comment: Hi @Sophie. This is a Great answer. Just for future reference, we do not need to add `<html>` and `<script>` tags in snippets.